# Do I benefit from using syncadapter in android?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, data-synchronization

I have a server that has php and mysql running. There are php scripts that return the data on the server in json format. This data is consumed by my android app. The app synchronizes the data with the server when it starts up and that takes about 2 minutes for the first time and about 20 seconds subsequently. Will I benefit by using syncadapter in my app so that the synchronizing at startup is avoided and the data is synchronized in the background as the app runs? Or will some other strategy will be more suitable.

Comment: Have you gotten any further with this? What was your new course of action? I have a similar concern as to whether it is worth it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31505857/do-i-need-a-syncadapter-given-websockects-and-gcm